# Enumerating on ConcurentDictionary

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrent-programming

If i use ConcurentDictionary dic in multithread accessed method can i be sure that in such construction:

```
foreach (Subscription sub in subscriptions[ex].Values)
                    {
                      ....
                    }
```

`subscriptions` is `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<long, Subscription>>` wont change when running by several methods, so that it will be thread save? Or should i use lock like:

```
lock(padLock)
{   
foreach (Subscription sub in subscriptions[ex].Values)
                        {
                          ....
                        }
}
```

to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary
>   are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

So yes, you will be safe without an extra lock, even if some other thread modifies the `Values` collection while you're iterating over it.

By *modifies* I mean that it adds new pairs or changes existing values in the dictionary.